# Add a type definition for a scoped package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-definition

I'm working with a package that has no types, so I created a type definition. The package is [react-date-range](https://github.com/casai-org/react-date-range), so I created a directory to put the type definitions: `src/types/react-date-range/index.d.ts` and everything worked fine.

But, because I needed to update the source code of `react-date-range` I forked the project and created a new npm package with the modification. The package is a [scoped public package](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages), and its name is now `@example-org/react-date-range`.

I'm trying to update the type definition to match the new name but I'm getting errors.

I changed the module name to `declare module "@example-org/react-date-range"` instead of `declare module "react-date-range"` but it didn't work. I also tried to put the type definitions on `src/types/@example-org/react-date-range/index.d.ts` and `src/types/@example-org__react-date-range/index.d.ts` but nothing of this worked.

This is my tsconfig file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I forked the project and created a new npm package with the modification

You could instead submit a pull request to the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) project, so one can install the types you created using:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-date-range
```

Packages from the DefinitelyTyped project are scoped with `@types`, and TypeScript automatically finds type definitions under `node_modules/@types`.

If you want to load your type definitions specifically from your package, then you'll need to specify it in `typeRoots` under the `compilerOptions`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/", "./node_modules/@example-org/react-date-range"]
  }
}
```

Check the [typeRoots documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) on the typescript site.